# How to nslog - copied text in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, copy, nslog

Suppose - User has selected & copied some text in textField/textView/webView.

Now I want to Log the copied text, But don't know how?

How is it possible?

Sagar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];

if ([pasteboard containsPasteboardTypes: [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"public.utf8-plain-text"]]) {
    NSLog(@"WE gots a string which is: %@", pasteboard.string);
}
```

Hope this help! ;)

Comment: For this to work properly on iOS 5 too you may need to write this up as `[pasteboard containsPasteboardTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"public.utf8-plain-text", @"public.text", nil]]` or indeed `[pasteboard containsPasteboardTypes:UIPasteboardTypeListString]`

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be to use the UIPasteBoard function:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPasteboard_Class/Reference.html

Hope that helps!

Comment: Just because it doesn't spoonfeed you the code doesn't mean its an indirect answer. Neruofluxation is pointing you in the exact direction you need to be looking. This site isn't a place to get work done for you.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here you go Sagar... It would be wise for you to research how this works though:

This code to Copy strings to the pasteBoard:

```
    -(IBAction)copyStringToPasteBoard{
       UIPasteboard *appPasteBoard = [UIPasteboard pasteboardWithName:@"CopyFrom" create:YES];
       appPasteBoard.persistent = YES;
       NSString *yourCopiedText = @"YOUR TEXT HERE";
       NSLog(@"\n Your String: %@",appPasteBoard.string);
       [appPasteBoard setString:textView.text];
    }
```

I hope this is more specific for you, please vote me up ^.^

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to objective-c development so I might be mistaking but shouldn't the NSLog row be below the "[appPasteBoard..."-row? You log the text before it is actually written to the pasteboard.

It is a brilliant example in any case and I used it with a little tweak. I wanted to use the general pasteboard so I ended up with this:

```
UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
pasteboard.persistent = YES;
NSString *yourCopiedText = @"YOUR TEXT HERE";
[pasteboard setString:yourCopiedText];
NSLog(@"\n String sent to pasteboard: %@",pasteboard.string);
```

Hope it can help anyone and thanks Neurofluxation for the example!

Regards
Henrik